# Telegram bot обработка сообщения, в разных обработчиках

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Всем привет!
Столкнулся с проблемой при создании бота и написания кода для него, а именно не понятно как на основании вводимого текста или же при нажатии на кнопку сменить обработчик в котором будет обработано сообщение.
Ну например:
с текстом который начинается на "drfo" пример:  "drfo я ввел текст" что б этот текст отправить в обработчик drfo, и аналогично в vibo
второй пример это когда есть две кнопки(Reply я так полагая) и при нажатии на одну из них менялся обработчик и весь текст который будет вводится далее будет обработан в этом обработчике.
Ниже кусочек кода, но его сильно порезали:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sqlite3
import logging
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters
import logging
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, Update
from telegram.ext import (
    Updater,
    CommandHandler,
    CallbackQueryHandler,
    ConversationHandler,
    CallbackContext,
)

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    level=logging.INFO)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def start(update, context):
     update.message.reply_text('')


def drfo(update, context):
    Код который не прошел в СБ


def vibo(update, context):
    Код который не прошел в СБ


def error(update, context):
    logger.warning('Update "%s" caused error "%s"', update, context.error)


def main():
    updater = Updater("TOKEN", use_context=True)
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, drfo))
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, vibo))
    dp.add_error_handler(error)
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Может кто подскажет как маршрутизировать текст по обработчикам

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать pyTelegramBotAPI

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['drfo'])
def drfo(message):
    pass

@bot.message_handler(commands=['vibo'])
def vibo(message):
    pass
```

Comment: Что то не совсем понимаю как интегрировать данный код в свой, что б получилось обрабатывать сообщение в зависимости от введенной команды

Comment: @IgorChernyenko надо импортировать апи и объявить бота по токену````import telebot
```` и ````bot = telebot.TeleBot("TOKEN", parse_mode=None)````
Но до этого, очевидно, надо установить api ````pip install pyTelegramBotAPI````

Answer (score 0):

Возможно этот материал будет Вам полезен:
[Examples](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/conversationbot2.py)

Есть так же схема маршрутизации диалога данного примера: [Scheme](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/conversationbot2.mmd)

```
    # Добавляем обработчик диалога со состояниями CHOOSING, TYPING_CHOICE и TYPING_REPLY
conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
    entry_points=[CommandHandler("start", start)],
    states={
        CHOOSING: [
            MessageHandler(
                filters.Regex("^(Age|Favourite colour|Number of siblings)$"), regular_choice
            ),
            MessageHandler(filters.Regex("^Something else...$"), custom_choice),
        ],
        TYPING_CHOICE: [
            MessageHandler(
                filters.TEXT & ~(filters.COMMAND | filters.Regex("^Done$")), regular_choice
            )
        ],
        TYPING_REPLY: [
            MessageHandler(
                filters.TEXT & ~(filters.COMMAND | filters.Regex("^Done$")),
                received_information,
            )
        ],
    },
    fallbacks=[MessageHandler(filters.Regex("^Done$"), done)],
)

application.add_handler(conv_handler)
```

Обратите внимание, что данный пример кода для версии 20.2 пакета python-telegram-bot у Вас по всей видимости версия предыдущая 13.*)